# Calculating $\int_A\langle v,n\rangle\, dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> > Consider 
> >     $$
> > A:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq 1\right\},\\
> > v\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3, (x,yz)\longmapsto (x^3,x^2y,zx^2).
> > $$
> >     Calculate
> >     $$
> > \int_A\langle v,n\rangle\, dS
> > $$
> >     where $n$ is the external unit normal field. Use two ways to do so: 1) surface integral 2) Gauß integral theorem.

1)

I used
$$
\Psi\colon [0,1]\times [-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^3, (\phi,z)\longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi\\\sin\phi\\z\end{pmatrix}
$$
as parametrization and so got
$$
\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2\phi\, d\phi\, dz=\pi
$$

So using surface integral i came to the solution $\pi$. Is that right?

2) How can I use the Gaussian integral theorem to calculate the integral?

I know that
$$
\int_A\mbox{div }v\, d^3x=\int_{\partial A}\langle v,n\rangle\, dS
$$
but do not know how to work with that here, because it's not the integral over $\partial A$ what is searched but over whole $A$.

Comment: The original problem shoukd be stated as a surface integral over $\partial A$. Otherwise, neither $n$ nor the application of Gauß makes sense.

Comment: Hm, okay. Then for 2) the integral is $20/3$?

Comment: No, the answer is $\pi$. However, your solution of (1) is flawed. $\partial A$ alsomhas the top and bottom disks; however, the flux across the top cancels the flux across the bottom, so your answer is correct.

Comment: Now I am confused: What is right and what is wrong?

Comment: Ah, I see. I did forget to parametrisize the cover and the ground of the cylinder. But because they cancel each other it did not cause a mistake.

Comment: But I do not see how the result is $\pi$ when using the Gaussian integral theorem. Because then I can use the integral of the divergence over $A$ and the divergence here is $5x^2$...

Comment: Oops, yeah, you're right, it's $5\pi/4$ (I'm seriously jetlagged). Moreover, the flux through top and bottom do *not* cancel, because $v\cdot n=0$ on the bottom and $=x^2$ on the top. This gives an additional $\pi/4$, as needed.

Comment: You mean I have to find a parametrization for bottom and top of the cylinder and then calculate those two surface integrals, too? And when I add this two integrals to the one I already calculated, I get $\frac{5}{4}\pi$?

Comment: Parametrization of the top: $\phi\colon [0,1]\times [-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^3, (u,v)\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}u\cos v\\u\sin v\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and one for the bottom is $\psi\colon [0,1]\times [-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^3, (u,v)\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}u\cos v\\u\sin v\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Be careful with orientations. The bottom disk has outward normal $(0,0,-1)$.

Comment: I have some problems to calculate $\int_T\langle v,n\rangle\, dS$, where T stands for the top of the cylinder. To my opinion its $\int_T x^2\, dS$, because $n((x,y,z)=e_3$ for all $(x,y,z)\in T$. And then with the parametrization of the top that I gave: $\int_T\langle v,n\rangle\, dS=\int_T x^2\, dS=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Is that right? But it has to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$...

Comment: SORRY, my mistake. I found the mistake!